# How to detect orphaned Unix socket files?

Tags: ssh, unix, tunnel

I have created a reverse SSH tunnel that creates a UNIX socket on a distant server (let's call it proxy_srv), so that I can connect the tunnel owner (named target_srv in the rest of this question) in 2 steps: creating a link from the Unix socket to a TCP port with `socat`, and connect to that port with a SSH client (SSH client does not seems to accept connecting to a Unix socket, so I used that `socat` trick as a workaround).

The commands involved are (enough to reproduce, a little more in practice, with identity files & co), in that order:

From target_srv:

```
me@target_srv:% ssh -CNR /tmp/$(hostname):127.0.0.1:22 me@proxy_srv -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
```

From proxy_srv:

```
me@proxy_srv:% socat TCP-LISTEN:2222 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/target_srv
```

From any other computer that can access proxy_srv:

```
ssh someone@proxy_srv
```

The goal of all this is to have a tunnel built automatically from machines that use GPRS networks to an access point so that I can access them in case of problems, considering the fact I do not have physical access to them (too many kilometers away).

I have 2 major problems:

- when someone deletes the Unix socket file on proxy_srv, the tunnel does not ends, so I can not recreate it (easy to workaround, just use a dedicated user, but still a little concerning to me),
- most importantly, if for some reason something on target_srv was restarted, either a physical reboot or a system crash with things going up automatically after, the file on proxy_srv is not deleted, and the tunnel can't be rebuilt.
  Of course, I could just delete it, and hope the problem is not a conflict with another computer, but I think there must be a better way to at least work around that, for example detecting socket files that no longer have listeners and automatically delete them regularly (inside a dedicated folder, of course).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand there are many target_srv machines and for this reason you don't use `-R 2222:127.0.0.1:22` but connect the `2222` port of proxy_srv to the machine of your choice ad hoc.

I think the right tool is VPN. If the proxy_srv was the VPN server and target_srv machines were clients, you would tunnel SSH to the (VPN) IP address of the desired client. If you made your local computer a client as well, you might even reach other clients semi-directly (without SSH tunneling). VPN software would be responsible for establishing, maintaining and renewing any target_srv's presence in the virtual network.

Suppose you cannot use VPN and this socket-based contraption of yours is a must. I don't know how to detect orphaned Unix domain sockets, however there's another way to deal with the situation.

Create a helper script on the proxy_srv, let's say `/home/me/bin/ssh-tunnel-helper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

soc1="$1".tmp
soc2="$1"

mv "$soc1" "$soc2" || { rm "$soc1"; exit 2; }
while sleep 40; do
   [ -e "$soc2" ] || exit 1
done
```

(Don't forget to make it executable).

Then on a target_srv invoke:

```
socket="/tmp/$(hostname)-tunnel"
while sleep 5; do
   ssh -CR "$socket".tmp:127.0.0.1:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes me@proxy_srv \
      /home/me/bin/ssh-tunnel-helper.sh "$socket"
done
```

Now

- > when someone deletes the unix socket file on proxy_srv

the `ssh-tunnel-helper.sh` script detects it and exits. The `while` loop on the target_srv renews the tunnel.

- > if for some reason something on target_srv was restarted, […] the file on proxy_srv is not deleted

The `*-tunnel` socket is indeed not deleted, but `sshd` initially creates `*-tunnel.tmp` which is renamed *later*. The trick is in Unix you can open a file and move it (or even delete it). Renaming the socket doesn't disturb the existing tunnel, yet allows a new socket to be created in the future.

If the helper script is interrupted it may leave a stale `*-tunnel.tmp` socket that would prevent future tunnels from being established. I expect such incidents to be rare. Run `rm /tmp/*-tunnel.tmp` on proxy_srv to recover. Even if you happen to remove *another* socket that was just about to be renamed at this very moment, its helper script will exit and the tunnel will be renewed in a while.

Note:

- You may want to use `autossh` instead of `ssh` on target_srv machines to detect broken connections etc. Even with `autossh` you still need the `while` loop because `autossh` will exit if the helper script exits (e.g. when someone deletes the socket on proxy_srv).